# Facebook auth.statusChange not firing after dialog in IE

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, callback, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on a website that uses the FB JS auth SDK, only to sign users in when they click the 'Login with Facebook' button, not to automatically log users in on page load or anything. As such, I have 'status' set to false in FB.init.

The following is my implementation of it:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ 
        appId: '73092430896', 
        status: false, 
        cookie: true, 
        xfbml: true, 
        oauth: true,
    });  

    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        console.log('login called.');
        if (response.authResponse) { 
            console.log('repsonse is set.');                    
            if(typeof APPJS.login != 'undefined' && typeof APPJS.login.loginCallback == 'function'){
                console.log('login.callback exists.');
                APPJS.login.loginCallback(response);
            }   
        }
    });            
};
```

The problem is, the auth.statusChange callback is not being fired in IE (any version I've tried), thus my users are not being logged in via my custom JS function. It works just fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. It has nothing to do with being logged in/out of Facebook in any of these browsers, I've tried being both logged in and out of Facebook but IE still doesn't make the call to the callback.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** Adding the channel parameter doesn't appear to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See "Checking user status on page load" section on this page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

It says you should set "status: true" in FB.init call.

Comment: But only if you want to automatically login when the page is loaded (if already logged into Facebook), correct? I have it set to false specifically because I only want it checking when the user clicks the login button, as my server handles its own sessions and only needs Facebook to validate the user for the initial login.